# How can I send a large message to WebSphere MQ through JMS?

Tags: size, jms, ibm-mq

There is a built in limitation of 2 MB for the IBM WebSphere MQ JMS interface.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21221260

Is there a way to bypass that limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limitation applied to WMQ versions distributed with WAS back at V5.1.1 many years ago.  If this is the problem, upgrading to current version of WMQ will resolve it.  The current version of WMQ is V7.0.1.  V6.0.2 is also still current but will be out of service in September of 2012.  V6 & V7 can send and receive messages up to 100MB but WMQ itself defaults to 4MB out of the box.  It is necessary to tune parameters of the QMgr, queues and channels if messages larger than 4MB are required but JMS is not a limitation at modern versions.

The WMQ Java/JMS manuals do not specifically mention a maximum size because it is the same as the native WMQ max length of 100MB.  However, the [WMQ V6 Performance Report](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007150) provides benchmarks for JMS messages up to 64MB.

Whatever is preventing you from putting a 3MB message isn't a limitation of WMQ's JMS implementation as regards message size.  If you have checked MAXMSGL on all of the channels and queues and the QMgr then it's something less obvious but it *is* configuration.

Comment: This is all true. However, the limitation I refer to is when using the JMS interface, and in that case I found no way to configure the limit above 2 MB

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a 2MB limit?  It is not part of the JMS specification, nor do the WMQ classes impose that limit.  Are you getting errors trying to put large messages?  If so, then it's probably MAXMSGL tuning in the queue, channel and/or QMgr imposing the limitation.

Comment: see the link in the original post:

Comment: Here is a snippet from the link:

Comment: Messages of 2 MB is the maximum supported size. While it is possible to change the max message size on the channels, it is not supported. If users want to send messages greater than 2MB's they will need to use external WebSphere® MQ.

Comment: But the post is more than 6 years old and refers to an out-of-service product.  Are you actually using V5.1.1?  If so, there is no configuration to get past this limitation.  If you are using a modern version of the product then the post linked to, and limitation described there, no longer apply.

Comment: OK, I'm using v 6.1. I configured the queue manager to 4 MB and fail on 3 MB with the exception from the post, so I have to assume the post is still relevant...

Comment: I've updated my answer with links to documentation for the V6 product showing where JMS message performance was benchmarked with 64MB messages.  There's something in the configuration that you are missing and the Technote linked to really doesn't apply.

Comment: Rob, I'll test that first thing tomorrow. Thanks alot

Comment: @T.Rob, the url [WMQ V6 Performance Report](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQ7G) seems to be invalid

Comment: D'oh!  Sorry.  I wrote http://bit.ly/SupportPacMQ7G where what was intended was http://bit.ly/SupportPacMP7G  I suppose I should QA my posts better!

Comment: Rob, you rock! just tested the configuration again and sent over 90 MB file :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might sound arduous, but it is a solution:

1. Take your message content, convert it into a byte array.
2. Split the byte array into ***n*** sub arrays that are ~< 1.9 MB each.
3. Start a JMS transaction and send each sub array in a ByteMessage, incrementing the group count:

e.g.

```
   message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", groupId);
   message.setIntProperty("JMSXGroupSeq", i);
```

On the receiver side, you implement a selector to get all the messages in the group as soon as you receive the first message. Retrieve all the messages in the group (hopefully you get them all), sort them correctly, re-create the big byte array, unmarshall it, and you're done.

Trivial really.....

Here's a [better example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0602_currie/0602_currie.html).

Comment: While this is good code golf, the premise of the question is wrong.  Hopefully we can address the root cause which has to be configuration or tuning and not "solve" it by programming around it.  The question is roughly equivalent to "How can I get my car to exceed the built-in limit of 45MPH?" and referencing a spec sheet from a Model-T Ford as proof that modern cars cannot exceed 45MPH.  Continuing the analogy, this answer is roughly the equivalent of "beef up the boiler so you can get more steam pressure."

Comment: It's *excellent* code golf. Furthermore, this approach is explicitly supported by WebSphere MQ: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/file_to_message.htm. Did Model-T Fords have boilers ?

Comment: Right - MQFTE splits files up, sends and reassembles msgs.  But it's solving a different problem.  Premise of OP was that IBM's JMS does not support msgs > 2MB which not only isn't true today, but at the time the referenced Technote was written was *only true for the WMQ bundled with WAS*! I'm all for a good coding challenge as long as it solves a real problem or everyone understands it's an academic exercise. In this case, OP truly believes the limit is real. Shouldn't we help solve the config/tuning problem rather than allow him to continue laboring under false understanding of the product?

Comment: On further research, I see Model-T's didn't have boilers although many cars of the time did. But it makes the point even better - if we are to solve a non-existent problem, a non-existent solution seems the perfect approach.

Comment: Nicholas, FYI I ran across this post and noted the link at the end is no longer valid.  I had asked IBM to republish it somewhere but as far as I know they never did.